Change "Powerbutton" to "run script"
I am trying to get used to modern Linux.
Running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on a
HP HP EliteDesk 800 G3 DM 35W / Intel® Pentium® G4560T × 4
What I want to do:
Map the Power-Button on the case (the only button) to "sudo reboot" (or an equivalent), instead of the default "Power Off in 60 seconds".
What I have tried:
#1 Editing /etc/systemd/logind.conf -> change (uncomment) HandlePowerKey= [does nothing]
#2 Editing /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet -> change
key  { [ XF86PowerOff ] };
to
key  { [ XF86XK_LaunchA ] };
This works – whichever key I put here seems to get handed to the system when I press the button.
But now I don't know how to use these XF86XK_Launch0-9 / XF86XK_LaunchA-F keys…
Since the XF86XK_ stuff doesn't seem to contain a "reset" or "reboot" member, I would effectively need to run a .sh, right?
The Ubuntu GUI for keybindings does not recognise the XF86XK_Launch buttons, but they get noticed by sudo showkey – XF86XK_LaunchA is keycode 116 for example [0xe0 0x5e 0xe0 0xde with the -s flag]
So what would be "the way" to have my machine run a script here?
Thanks!
